# How to perturb an adjacency matrix in order to have the highest increase in spectral radius?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Let's suppose I have a generic directed graph $G$ and it's adjacency matrix $A$. I can add an arc wherever I want in the graph. (i.e. perturb the matrix $A$ changing a single $0$ into a $1$). 
Where should I put that one to have the highest increase in the biggest eigenvector as possible?

I suppose that the answer is "where you can connect the two largest strongly connected components".

Comment: looking at the undirected graph $A^T A$ or $A^T+A$ instead of $A$ would be easier ?

Answer (score 1):

These two papers should be helpful for you.

[1] J. G. Restrepo, E. Ott, and B. R. Hunt, Phys. Rev. Lett. 97, 094102 (2006)

[2] A. Milanese, J. Sun, and T. Nishikawa, Phys. Rev. E 81, 046112, (2010)